# C++ Object value suddenly becomes NULL with no related prior instruction

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

*NOTE: Reopened question with more details.*

So here we have some code

### someCode.cpp

```cpp
(...)
MyStruct sct = performRequest(.... .... ....); //Line 1
std::cout << "Line 2";
std::cout << "Line 3";
(...)
```

### someCode.hpp (*for* `struct MyStruct`)

```cpp
(...)
struct MyStruct {
    char** memory;
    int* response_code;
};
(...)
```

### performRequest() function

```cpp
static size_t
WriteMemoryCallback(void* contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* userp)
{
    size_t realsize = size * nmemb;
    struct MemoryStruct* mem = (struct MemoryStruct*)userp;

    char* ptr = (char*) realloc(mem->memory, mem->size + realsize + 1);
    if (ptr == NULL) {
        /* out of memory! */
        printf("not enough memory (realloc returned NULL)\n");
        return 0;
    }

    mem->memory = ptr;
    memcpy(&(mem->memory[mem->size]), contents, realsize);
    mem->size += realsize;
    mem->memory[mem->size] = 0;

    return realsize;
}



MyStruct performRequest(std::string requestType, std::string URL, std::string requestParameters, struct curl_slist* headersList, std::string requestFields) {
    CURL* curl_handle = curl_easy_init();
    CURLcode curl_code;
    

    struct MemoryStruct chunk;

    chunk.memory = (char*) malloc(1);  /* will be grown as needed by the realloc above */
    chunk.size = 0;    /* no data at this point */

    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, 102400L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, (URL + requestParameters).c_str());
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, true);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
    if (!requestFields.empty()) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, requestFields.c_str());
    }

    if (headersList != NULL) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headersList);
    }
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 50L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, requestType.c_str());
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, false);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPALIVE, true);

    /* send all data to this function, we pass our 'chunk' struct to the callback function   */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteMemoryCallback);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void*)& chunk);

    curl_code = curl_easy_perform(curl_handle);

    /* check for errors */
    if (curl_code != CURLE_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
            curl_easy_strerror(curl_code));
    }

    int response_code;
    curl_easy_getinfo(curl_handle, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &response_code);

    /* cleanup curl stuff */
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl_handle);

    MyStruct res;
    res.memory = &chunk.memory;
    res.response_code = &response_code;

    return res;
}
```

If we debug `someCode.cpp` and add two breakpoints in lines 2 and 3...

```cpp
    (...)
    MyStruct sct = performRequest(···,···,···); //Line 1
    [BREAKPOINT (1) HERE] std::cout << "Line 2";
    [BREAKPOINT (2) HERE] std::cout << "Line 3";
    (...)
```

...see the following images about the resulting values by the debugger, for the struct `sct`.
[image: Breakpoint 1]
*(which corresponds to Breakpoint 1)* **:)**

[image: Breakpoint 2]
*(which corresponds to Breakpoint 2)* **:(**

As you can see, the values in `sct` change to `NULL` without prior instruction. I don't know why this happens, although I suspect it might be something pointer-related...

So to deal with the object lifetime (`sct`), I changed `performRequest()` to this:

```
RequestResponse* performRequest(···) {
    (···)
    return new RequestResponse(&chunk.memory,&response_code);
}
```

but still I have the same problem.
Hope you have any idea and thanks!

Comment: I see C++ but also `char**` which has me wondering...why?

Comment: You're showing `MyStruct`, but not the `MemoryStruct` you're allocating. Since this is C++ why are you specifying `struct` every time? Why not use `new` instead of `malloc`? Also use `nullptr` in preference to C's `NULL`.

Comment: `char* ptr = (char*) realloc(mem->memory, mem->size + realsize + 1);` - I would expect to see something like this in a C program, but *not* in a C++ program.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is right here:

```
MyStruct res;
res.memory = &chunk.memory;
res.response_code = &response_code;

return res;
```

You're supplying `res` with the address of two local variables. So the second that function ends and you return the struct with those pointers, they're both invalid. Thus leading to this undefined behavior.

You *could* allocate new pointers on the heap there and seed them with the values of `chunk.memory` and `response_code`. Since they're on the heap, they'll persist until you free the memory, so that'd work.

However, I'd strongly suggest moving to a `std::vector<std::string>` instead of your `char**` and move to a raw `int` instead of `int*` if possible so you don't even need to worry about UB like this.

Comment: i.e. exactly what we said it would be, the last time you asked this question ;)

Comment: @Asteroid do you have a link? I'd much rather close this as a dupe

Comment: I think it was deleted

Comment: I tried to do this `RequestResponse* performRequest(···) {(···)
 return new RequestResponse(&chunk.memory,&response_code);
}` but still I have the same problem.

Comment: @ElJaviLuki you misunderstand I'm saying you'd have to (but *absolutely* not suggesting you) do `res.memory = new char*(chunk.memory);` and `res.response_code = new int(response_code);`

Comment: Why would we need a `std::vector<std::string>` if you only want to keep one string and not a bunch of them?

Comment: @ElJaviLuki I could turn the question back to you. Why would you need a `char **` when you only want to store one `char *`? My assumption from that was that you'd be storing multiple. But if you aren't, then just an `std::string` is enough.